# start process not working for remote servers

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

using PowerShell, i'm trying to install windows patch update in multiple remote servers using command start-process, it is working in the local server but it is not installing in remote servers. please help me with this stuck, over a long time. thanks in advance

```
$Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers  -Credential $mycreds  -ScriptBlock {
    $destination = "C:\patches\KB5023333.msu"
    Start-Process -FilePath "wusa.exe"  -ArgumentList "/quiet", "/restart", `"$destination`" -Wait  -PassThru
}
```

Comment: there is no error still is not installing the patch

Comment: You can use `-RedirectStandardOut` and `-RedirectStandardError` to capture the process' output in files, which may provide clues. Also, if you capture the process-info object returned by `Start-Process -PassThru`, you can examine its `.ExitCode` property.